# How to toggle a single checkbox on click of a different element?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to find a cleaner and simpler way to check and uncheck a checkbox when I click on a div element. This is the code I'm currently using which works for checking, but unchecking isn't working.

http://codepen.io/jimmykup/full/xkoqJ

I understand what I've written could be done in a faster and/or simpler way, but I'm at a loss as to how.

Note: I'm working with a checkbox that is going to be inserted via javascript.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <input type="checkbox" class="confirm" name="ld_Confirm" id="ld_Confirm"><div class="click-me unchecked">Click here to check the checkbox.</div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function() {

$('.click-me').before('<input type="checkbox" class="confirm" name="ld_Confirm" id="ld_Confirm">');

$(".container .click-me.unchecked").click(function() {
  $(".confirm").prop("checked", true);
  $(".click-me").toggleClass("unchecked");
  $(".click-me").toggleClass("checked");
});

$(".container .click-me.checked").click(function() {
  $(".confirm").prop("checked", false);
  $(".click-me").toggleClass("unchecked");
  $(".click-me").toggleClass("checked");
});

})();
```

Comment: you are trying to bind a click event to an element that doesn't exist when the page is loaded

Comment: I think he means the div is there on page load , not the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a `click` event handler on document load, but since you're toggling the class of the container, the handler isn't being bound to the `div`. In other words: at the time the code is loaded, there are no `div`s with class `unchecked`, so that event handler isn't bound to anything.

The quick solution is to use *event delegation* to bind the handler dynamically:

```
$(".container").on('click','.click-me.unchecked',function() {
    $(".confirm").prop("checked", true);
    $(".click-me").toggleClass("unchecked");
    $(".click-me").toggleClass("checked");
});
$(".container").on('click','.click-me.checked',function() {
    $(".confirm").prop("checked", false);
    $(".click-me").toggleClass("unchecked");
    $(".click-me").toggleClass("checked");
});
```

However, a better approach exists. You can streamline your code immensely by just setting the checkbox's `checked` property to its own inverse. By doing so you remove the need for delegation and, indeed, the need for `checked` and `unchecked` classes entirely (assuming you're not also using them for styling or in some other script):

```
$(".container").on('click','.click-me',function() {
    $(".confirm").prop("checked", !$(".confirm").prop("checked"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/bNkxG/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.click-me').click(function() {
    var checkBoxes = $(".confirm");
    checkBoxes.attr("checked", !checkBoxes.attr("checked"));
});
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177159/jquery-toggle-checkboxes-on-off)

you could always try to search google or SO , for "jquery toggle checkbox "

incase this div is not  going to be there on document load

```
$(document).on( 'click' , '.click-me', (function() {
    var checkBoxes = $(".confirm");
    checkBoxes.attr("checked", !checkBoxes.attr("checked"));
});
```

it shouldn't matter if the checkbox with class '.confirm' was there on page load, as long as that is there when this click is fired