# jQuery why changing the text is hiding the checkbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am chaging the text of a textbox, and its upating a label, but its hiding the checkbox? Can any one tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here

http://jsfiddle.net/6mZbm/6/

Here

```
<input type="text" id="txtInput" width="80px" />
</br>
<label id="lbl" />
</br>
</br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkUpdate" />
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {

    $('#txtInput').keydown(function(event) {

        $('#lbl').text($('#txtInput').val());
        $('#lbl').change();
    });


    $('#lbl').change(function(event) {
        // alert($('#chkUpdate').size());
        $('#chkUpdate').change();
    });


});
```

**Okay, I closed the label tag it's still not working...
Check the updated fiddle.**

**EDIT 2** Okay its working now, but I am not getting what I wanna do, as should be clear from the code, I want to `check` `uncheck` (basically change) the checkbox, when the label is updated, but as you can see in the fiddle(s) (mine and the one Muthu Kumaran provided) the checkbox is not changing its state?

**EDIT 3 :** This seems to work with `click()` instead of `change()`, but as per [jQuery specification](http://api.jquery.com/change/), shouldn't it work with change too??

Comment: oopsy, add /> at the end of your label

Comment: what are you **trying** to do?

Comment: @goldenparrot:
Updated the question

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177159/jquery-toggle-checkboxes-on-off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you didn't close the `<label>` tag,

Close the label tag and it work properly

```
<label id="lbl"></label>
```

**Update:**
Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6mZbm/8/

Comment: so, we can't close label like this? ` />` The way I closed checkbox and input?

Comment: you can use / to close single tags for eg. <input/> or <img/> but you needn't do - else use <tag></tag> - <label> is a container (that can contain other tags) so therefore you need to close it the html way (not xhtml or xml style)

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the text of your `<label>` which includes your checkbox, get your checkbox out of label tag.

Answer (score 0):

just put

```
<label id="lbl"></label>
```