# Jquery Toggle Checkbox

Tags: jquery

So I have an issue. I'm trying to toggle checkboxes in order to add some css to the parent `<tr>`

This is what I have so far

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').toggle(function(){

    $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selectCheckBox', 970);
},
function(){

    $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selectCheckBox', 970);
});
```

However, the result of this is that the `<tr>` does receieve the `selectCheckBox` but the checkbox does not become checked. So I tried the following:

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').toggle(function(){
    $(this).attr('checked',true);
    $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selectCheckBox', 970);
},
function(){
    $(this).attr('checked',false);
    $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selectCheckBox', 970);
});
```

Once again, no luck.

I believe it has to do with how the checkbox id looks.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select[]" id="select[]">
```

I then tried escaping the `[]` by using `\\[\\]` as I've used in the past, but no luck.

Is there a way to make the `checkbox` checked?

Comment: see here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177159/toggle-checkboxes-on-off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to use toggleClass along with the rest of jQuery UI parameters to get the effect needed.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('selectCheckBox',  1000, "easeOutSine" );
});

// Here are the parameteres below
    .toggleClass( className [, switch ] [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try on `change` event. Also as I think `toggle` event is deprecated and `addClass` doesn't take a second parameter (unless you're using jQuery UI).

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('selectCheckBox', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: Awesome!! This worked perfectly. I thought of the change event, but didn't think it'd work!

THe addClass has the second parameter to ease in the effect of the class. it fades it in.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way to optimize this a bit more:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        $this.closest('tr').addClass('selectCheckbox');
    } else {
        $this.closest('tr').removeClass('selectCheckbox');
    }
});
```

​
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VcEm/)