# Jquery click check nearest checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to use a link to check a checkbox with jQuery. My HTML is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="test" /></td>
    <td><a class="editbutton" href="#">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have been playing with this jquery:

```
jQuery('.editbutton').click(function($) {
    jQuery(this).closest('[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ever heard about HTML Labels? They do this without any JavaScript.

Comment: @epascarello Post it as answer, I would certainly upvote.

Comment: [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) looks for the closest ancestor element. You need to do a little more [tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: @epascarello I have no control over the checkbox or much on the HTML in general, hence the jQuery!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`, Because `.prop` is made for setting the `properties`. By the way your selector is wrong. `.closest()` will traverse up the dom tree.

Please read the following for more reference : 
[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)  [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Try this,

```
jQuery('.editbutton').click(function($) {
    jQuery(this).closest('td').prev().find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Or as @kappa suggested.

```
jQuery('.editbutton').click(function($) {
    jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Xuz/1/)

Comment: If you simply look for the closest tr, you do not need that `prev`.

Comment: @kappa I just thought that, hooking up `tr` will need more traversals. Am I thinking right.? Please clarify.

Comment: Sounds like microoptimization to me. Relying on prev is quite vulnerable - you might add another cell between the two later. I don't say your solution is wrong, just added an alternative.

Comment: @quite `vulnerable for future modifications`. Great point. Thank you. Updated accordingly.

Comment: +1, excellent answer, i hope you implement a [toggle check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177175/7735285) function. that's the point of checkbox.