# Jquery to check and uncheck the checkboxes on if statement

Tags: jquery

Since I am new to Jquery, I want a code in JQUERY for following function:

```
if(checkbox.checked==true)
{
checkbox.checked=false;
}
else
checkbox.checked=true;
```

please help me with this.

Comment: `$(checkbox).prop("checked")`. Also you don't need to check if is true. You can sum it up to `checkbox.checked ? checbox.checked = false : checkbox.checked = true`

Comment: if I used this code previously:$(checkbox).removeAttr("checked")       
Then, is it possible to use this?   $(checkbox).prop("checked")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle Checkboxes on/off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177159/toggle-checkboxes-on-off)

Comment: `checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;`

Comment: Np, also check @Vohuman comment. Is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $checkbox = $(/*your selector*/);
$checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code: (Using [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/))

```
var checkbox = $('#targetId');
if(checkbox.prop('checked')==true)
checkbox.prop('checked','false');
else
checkbox.prop('checked','true');
```

OR

```
var checkbox = $('#targetId');
if(checkbox.attr('checked')=='checked')
checkbox.attr('checked','checked');
else
checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
```

- [**Single Checkbox demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/su7cw4u1/)
- [**Multiple Checkbox Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/su7cw4u1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#YourIdSelector,.YourClassSelector").click(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked',!$(this).is(':checked'));
    });                 
});
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

See this snippet:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked />
<input type="checkbox"  />
<input type="checkbox" checked />
<input type="checkbox"  />
<br /><br />
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Invert" />
```