# Jquery toggle two divs upon checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two tabs as shown:

```
<div class="tab-content">

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="script-submit">
       <input type="checkbox" id="cflow_flag"> Enable Coverage report<br>
       <button type="button" id="submit-job"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="commit-view">
       <button type="button" id="submit-cflow" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

upon checking/unchecking the box i need to toggle the `$('#script-submit #submit-job)` button with the `$('#commit-view #submit-cflow')` button

Note: Please note that only one out of the two tabs, `#script-submit` and `#commit-view` will be active at any given time

Comment: See this answer for a push in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177159/toggle-checkboxes-on-off

Comment: Were's your code, what have you tried. We are here to help, but only if you've tried it and showed us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide one of them by default with CSS and apply this jQuery script, using `toggle()` on both:

```js
jQuery('#cflow_flag').on("change", function() {
  jQuery('#submit-job').toggle();
  jQuery('#submit-cflow').toggle();
});
```

```css
#submit-cflow {
  display: none; 
  color: green;
}
#submit-job {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="script-submit">
       <input type="checkbox" id="cflow_flag"> Enable Coverage report<br>
       <button type="button" id="submit-job"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="commit-view">
       <button type="button" id="submit-cflow" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have implemented an answer which i am not completely happy with but does that trick for me. I would like to see if there is a sophisticated solution

```
<div class="tab-content">

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="script-submit">
       <input type="checkbox" id="cflow_flag"> Enable Coverage report<br>
       <button type="button" id="submit-job"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       <button type="button" id="submit-cflow" class="btn btn-primary hidden">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="commit-view">
       <button type="button" id="submit-cflow" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

and my JS is

```
$('#script-submit #cflow_flag').change(function(){
  $('#script-submit #submit-job').toggleClass('hidden');
  $('#script-submit #submit-cflow').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```