# Toggle switch to call url but not open it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a toggle switch on my html which i would like to enable/disable a relay in arduino with.

On: call http://192.168.1.144:8000/1234!Q02=0$
Off: call http://192.168.1.144:8000/1234!Q02=1$

I don't want the url to be opened, i just want it to be called.

```
function getValue1() {
   var isChecked = document.getElementById("button1").checked;

   if(isChecked){ 
     alert("button1 is checked");
   } else {
     alert("button1 is NOT checked");
   }
}
```

My javascript code is working, but i dont know how to call the url.

Thanks.

Comment: *but i dont know how to call the url.* what do you mean by *call the url*?

Comment: _I don't want the url to be opened, i just want it to be called._ What do you mean ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: Well, this url http://192.168.1.144:8000/1234!Q02=1$, will switch the relay on once called, because my arduino is connected to a wifi module to the same network. So I want to call this url when the toggle switch is on, and call it also when toggle switch is off. I don't want to get a response back. Just call the url.

Comment: The page I linked will give you code to do exactly that - fire and forget - you don't have to handle a response.

Comment: [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Like `fetch('http://192.168.1.144:8000/1234!Q02=' + !~~isChecked)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnCall").click(function(){
        var isChecked = document.getElementById("button1").checked;
        if(isChecked){ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://192.168.1.144:8000/1234!Q02=0$",
                data: JSON.stringify(data), //yourData
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                dataType: "json"
           });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://192.168.1.144:8000/1234!Q02=1$",
            data: JSON.stringify(data), //yourData
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Why did you give a jQuery answer when it's neither tagged nor asked for?

Comment: For future reference, please explain your answers.  This answer is of zero use to anyone who doesn't understand *why* this solves the problem, which means it's of no use to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you know how to update a html toggle switch using a result in an array in javascript?
So if the array has 1, the toggle switch will be updated to checked,
else if 0, the toggle switch will be updated to not checked

Comment: @MoatazM.Moussa

Comment: @MoatazM.Moussa Is JavaScript Necessary? Why don't you try jQuery?

Comment: @MoatazM.Moussa [Reffer This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177159/toggle-checkboxes-on-off)

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnCall").click(function(){

        if($("button1").prop('checked')){ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://192.168.1.144:8000/1234!Q02=0$",
                data: JSON.stringify(data), //yourData
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                dataType: "json"
           });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://192.168.1.144:8000/1234!Q02=1$",
            data: JSON.stringify(data), //yourData
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know how to update a html toggle switch using a result in an array in javascript? So if the array has 1, the toggle switch will be updated to checked, else if 0, the toggle switch will be updated to not checked –